# Getting coordinates of Geo image in python

Tags: python

I am using python64 bit. I have created the map which is consists of 4-5 shape files, take the Image file(.bmp) of it & opened in to the python. Now I want to display all the coordinates(longitude , latitude) where pointer moves on the Image. I have used the following code.

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.display.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1576, 847))
mapImg = pygame.image.load("gis12.bmp")

one = False

while not done:

    window.fill((0,0,0))
    evtList = pygame.event.get()
    for evt in evtList:
        if evt.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True

   window.blit(mapImg, (0,0))
   pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()'
```

Comment: To display the mouse coordinates, you will need to catch a pygame event for MOUSE_MOVE or similar. You may also want to catch the MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP events as well. See the pygame documentation for more help.

Comment: Getting longitude, latitude coordinates will depend on the map projection being used for the map. You would need to know this plus some information about what proportion of the sphere your map covers.